# Cannot resize chart from chart.js

Tags: html, css, charts, resize, chart.js

I have a flex container with a div inside of which I have a canvas with a chart from chart.js (maintainAspectRatio: false). The chart updates itself when I click on some buttons (changes its values and y-axis range). The div has some height and width specified:

```
<div id="chart-container"
    class="flex-item chart_class">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

where the classes "flex-item" and "chart_class" are the following ones:

```
.flex-item{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.chart_class{
    width:800px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I want the chart to reduce its size when I reduce the screen size. For this I implemented the following (for example for 768px):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .chart_class {
        width: 75%;
        height: 75%;
    }
}
```

This makes the chart successfully reduce its size, but when I click on the buttons to interact with it and the chart is reloaded with its new values, I get the following error in the console, and the size of the plots looks totally awkward:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStyle' of null - Chart.min.js:formatted:3626

Does anyone have any idea how I could resize and avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to unload the chart on resize, then reload it with the new size. It doesn't take much. I'm sure any other research here for Javascript will be good, like refactoring code, it all comes in sweet little packages.

Remember that you can have your handlers setup to invoke upon certain changes and give them the attention you need to.

Comment: Please, as per the rules, use the comments if you don't have to post code.

Comment: I don't have 50 rep yet. I cannot. Therefore I have to abide to the ruling archetype of the site's designer's intent, be it forward or backwards legacy. It'll just have to be what it is now. Sorry.